# Top command: How to stick to one unit (KB/KiB)

Tags: linux, bash

I'm using the `top` command in several distros to feed a Bash script. Currently I'm calling it with `top -b -n1`.

I'd prefer a unified output in KiB or KB. However, it will display large units in megabytes or gigabytes. Is there an option to avoid these large units?

Please consider the following example:

```
4911 root      20   0  274m 248m 146m S      0 12.4   0:07.19 example
```

Edit: To answer 123's question, I transform the columns and send them to a log monitoring appliance. If there's no alternative, I'll convert the units via awk beforehand as per [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/237412/handy-parsing-for-numbers-with-unit-suffixes).

Comment: What are you using top for? Like what it the end goal?

Comment: there's [htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/), tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider cutting out the middleman `top` and reading directly from [`/proc/[1-9]*/statm`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). All those files consist of one line of numbers, of which the first three correspond with `top`'s `VIRT  RES  SHR`, respectively, in units of pages, normally 4096 B, so that by multiplying with 4 you get units of KiB.

Answer (score 0):

You need a config file. You can create it yourself as `$HOME/.toprc` or using top interactively. The latter is easy. You just need to press `W` while `top` is running in interactive mode.

But first you need to set top interactively to the state you want. To change the memory scale press `e` until you see what you want. (Then save with `W`.)

Either way, you need this set in your config: `Task_mscale=0` for the lowest scale.